# What is the correct CSS syntax to set the text color in a nav tag without using bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, colors, nav

I was able to change the font family but for some reason the text decoration and color will not change.  I cannot use bootstrap and am doing this in css.  The cornsilk color is not happening

```css
nav {
    font-family: RockSalt-Regular;
    color: cornsilk;
    padding: 20px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: black;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
}
#menu-icon {
    display: hidden;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    background: #4C8FEC url(../img/menu-icon.png) center;
}
a:hover#menu-icon {
    background-color: #444;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
}
ul {
    list-style: none;
}
```

```html
    <nav>
        <a href="#" id="menu-icon"></a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#work">Work</a></li>
          <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

Learning how css works takes like 2 days.

```
nav a{
    color: cornsilk;
    }
```

If its already defined you might need to add !important to the end.

```
nav a{
     color: cornsilk!important;
      }
```

Also this doesnt work

```
a:hover#menu-icon {
    background-color: #444;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
}
```

This might

```
#menu-icon:hover {
    background-color: #444;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  I am working on making it responsive and trying to get the hamburger menu icon to be hidden until I put in media queries